# Is it safe to use non-archive mode when starting a parachain collator?

Tags: parachain

For example, when connecting to polkadot/kusama, can we use some sort of DB snapshot like [polkashots](https://polkashots.io/) to bypass the long waiting time?

However, it requires the non-archive mode in the relaychain command line, e.g. `--unsafe-pruning --pruning=1000`, is it safe to use it? Or can it bring about any negative effect given that the states that are older than 1000 blocks were pruned?

Answer (score 5):

> For example, when connecting to polkadot/kusama, can we use some sort of DB snapshot like polkashots to bypass the long waiting time?

Yes you can use snapshots.

> However, it requires the non-archive mode in the relaychain command line, e.g. --unsafe-pruning --pruning=1000, is it safe to use it? Or can it bring about any negative effect given that the states that are older than 1000 blocks were pruned?

The relay chain full node is running in non-archive node by default. Only the collator, aka the parachain db, is running in archive mode, but you are also allowed to run this in non-archive mode. We will revert the requirement of "validators == archive nodes" in the near future.